# MSSQL - 2TB Database - New file in Primary Group

Tags: sql-server

I have yet to find a good answer to this online.

The issue:
I have a 2TB database with only one table (archive). Unfortunately, the hard drive will soon be full and I need to somehow split data.
An extension of the hard disk is not possible in the short term. But there is another hard disk where I could store data on it. This one is 1TB in size.
The database has only one primary filegroup and one file to it.
If I add a new file to the filegroup, can I put this file on the 1TB and the database then writes its data there?

Comment: Yes, but be careful -- as long as the first file isn't empty (and/or can still grow) the engine will try to fill them proportionally, meaning some data will still go to the first file until the disk is truly full, and of course your database will then be contained in multiple files on multiple disks, so if one of the disks fails, the whole of the database becomes inaccessible. (Of course this is the case for one file on one disk by definition, but you might think that somehow you could still access the "new" data if the first disk fails -- not so.)

Comment: If you can add another filegroup you can partition the table across them. MSSQLTips has an article on how to partition an existing table here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2888/how-to-partition-an-existing-sql-server-table/ which gives more control than the proportional fill of an additional file

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert OK, perfect. But I can set a maximum size for the first file? That should solve it?

Comment: Yes, if you set autogrowth to 0 for the first file it will stop growing and stay the size it's now. There may still be some empty space in the existing file that will be used, but that's probably not much of an issue. (Do not shrink the file in any case, or if you do, do it with `TRUNCATEONLY`.)

Answer (score 3):

> If I add a new file to the filegroup, can I put this file on the 1TB and the database then writes its data there?

Yes.  SQL Server uses a "proportional fill algorithm" when a filegroup has multiple files.

> Filegroups use a proportional fill strategy across all the files
> within each filegroup. As data is written to the filegroup, the SQL
> Server Database Engine writes an amount proportional to the free space
> in the file to each file within the filegroup, instead of writing all
> the data to the first file until full. It then writes to the next
> file. For example, if file f1 has 100 MB free and file f2 has 200 MB
> free, one extent is given from file f1, two extents from file f2, and
> so on. In this way, both files become full at about the same time, and
> simple striping is achieved.

[File and Filegroup Fill Strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver15#file-and-filegroup-fill-strategy)

So if you add a new file, all (or almost all) of the new allocations will be from that file.  And so you can easily add usable space by adding a new file to your primary filegroup.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new file to your primary filegroup, data will be distributed in another disk as per your requirement. Even you can add more log files as well.
in your case, if the log file size is high then you can move your log file(.ldf) to another disk.